# What are 'tasks' in multi-task/transfer learning, linking to co-regionalisation

Tags: machine-learning, gaussian-process, multitask-learning

I am currently working on implementing a multi-task model for Gaussian process prediction, but am having some trouble interpreting the materials online (conference talks, papers, presentations/slides from the authors, etc.) as a lot of what is described is understandably assumed knowledge that I'm slowly working my head around.

Note: apologies for the raw links below, as I couldn't post more than 2 proper ones given my <10 reputation.

The paper in particular I'm looking at is Bonilla et al's paper (papers.nips.cc/paper/3189-multi-task-gaussian-process-prediction.pdf). What specifically does each 'task' refer to in multi-task learning - is it the relationship between features, or something else entirely?

I've been (perhaps incorrectly) trying to link the logic of it to a co-regionalisation tutorial here (nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/SheffieldML/notebook/blob/master/GPy/coregionalized_regression_tutorial.ipynb), where there is an improvement on a standard GP's result from the below:
[image: Standard GP]

To this:
[image].

This would lead me to think that it is a correlation between features that allows the improved model - but then, I am left confused as to how that would differ from the covariance between the training and test sets in this simple dataset.

I also realise there is only a single output here (with other threads on Cross Validated saying multiple outputs is a necessary but not sufficient condition of multi-task learning - stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161025/in-the-context-of-anns-is-there-multi-task-learning-iff-the-network-has-more-th), but this paragraph in the paper mentioned above:

> In the geostatistics literature, the prior model for f· given in eq. (1) is known as the intrinsic correlation
>   model [7], a specific case of co-kriging. A sum of such processes is known as the linear
>   coregionalization model (LCM) [7] for which [6] gives an EM-based algorithm for parameter estimation.

Has left me unsure on that front as well.

Any help regarding what the tasks are in a concrete example in multi-task learning and how they relate to the simple 1D coregionalisation example (if applicable) would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!